# Add values to Audit table

Tags: sql, informatica

I have to maintain an AUDIT table having columns year,month and status. How do I load data into it dynamically. Like year is 2016, month is 1 and status as Y. How do I do it for all years and months from 2016-2019 and more coming ahead.

it should look like this in 3 columns:

```
Year    Month    Status
2016    1        Y
2016    2        Y
2016    3        N
.
.
.
2019     10      Y
```

It should dynamically update for upcoming years as well like in future if 2021 comes then it should update accordingly.

I have to achieve this using Informatica.

Comment: you can write insert script

Answer (score 1):

**You can find like this:**

```
    SELECT TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (TO_DATE ('01.12.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), LEVEL),
                    'YYYY') YOUR_YEAR,
           TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (TO_DATE ('01.12.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), LEVEL),
                    'MM')YOUR_MONTH,
           'YOUR_STATUS' YOUR_STATUS
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
              MONTHS_BETWEEN (TO_DATE ('01.10.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),
                              TO_DATE ('01.12.2015', 'dd.mm.yyyy'))
```

Comment: you can generate script using this and then copy paste to informatica